# How to make python of exponential growth to code equivalent to c++?

Tags: python, c++

In this code I am computing a numerical approximation of the solution of an ODE u'(tk)=u(tk)=uk and storing all the uk and tk values as shown below.

Code:

```
def compute_u(u0,T,n):
    t = linspace(0,T,n+1)
    t[0] = 0
    u=zeros(n+1)
    u[0]= u0
    dt = T/float(n)
    for k in range(0, n, 1):
        u[k+1] = (1+dt)*u[k]
        t[k+1] = t[k] + dt
    return u, t
```

I am now trying to implement this code into c++ and I am facing a few rocks along the way. I am relatively new in C++ and I was wondering if anyone in this forum could point me to the right direction since python has functions that c++ does not such as linspace or zeros. Any input will be helpful.

Comment: Your `linspace` and `zeroes` do not come with raw python. It's from some package you are using. You should post the code if that's your own function, or find some equivalent library in C++. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Is there an equivalent library in c++?

Comment: Ah, I don't know which library you use in Python. But as a simple guess from your name, linspace might be something about 'linear space'. In this case, please take a look at yar's suggestion, the 'Eigen' library, which is a good linear algebra library in C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have linspace:

```
std::vector< float > linspace(float a, float b, uint32_t n)
{
    std::vector< float > result(n);
    float step = (b - a) / (float) (n - 1);

    for (uint32_t i = 0; i <= n - 2; i++) {
        result[i] = a + (float) i * step;
    }
    result.back() = b;

    return result;
}
```

try out zeros yourself.

Or a better solution: use [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page), it has both functions.